# db2 delete from result set in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, db2, resultset

I have written a stored procedure that includes a SELECT on a number of tables that applies logic to calculate values and transforms some of the data.

I have been asked if I can exclude records from the resultset in the stored procedure and write the record to a separate log table.  I was looking to loop through the result set from the SELECT statement and delete the record I want to exclude once I have written it to a table.  At the moment I am struggling to find the syntax to delete from the result set of a SELECT statement in a stored procedure and can only find how to use the cursor reference to delete from the original database table.

I need to remove the records in the same stored procedure and I am looking to avoid duplicating the logic by using some of the logic to find the records to include and repeat some of the logic again to be able to find the records to exclude.  The only other alternative I can think of is using a temporary table, but I think what I am trying to do should be possible.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an open cursor in a stored procedure (or in an application), you can perform positioned deletes.  You can execute the statement,

```
DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF cursorname;
```

Please be aware that by default issuing a `COMMIT` statement will close any open cursors, so if you plan to have this delete operation spread over multiple transactions you will need to declare your cursors using `WITH HOLD`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm having problems with the syntax.  I am using data studio and it is underlining 'OF' as an error.  A sample of the code I am using is    

start_loop: LOOP
    IF SQLCODE = 0 THEN
        FETCH cursor1 INTO v_id;
            DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF cursor1;
   ELSE
        LEAVE start_loop;
   END IF;
END LOOP start_loop;